# How to notify a user with SMS or notification when needed

Tags: android

So in my app I'm looking to have the students class schedules and the times which they need to be in class.

When the app is turned off I still want the notification to pop up that their class is about to start (possibly vibrate).

This sort of functionality is very akin to an incoming text message or notification of something like an email. I was wondering how to implement that into an app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use the [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) to set an alarm when you require the notification, possibly with the [RTC_WAKEUP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#RTC_WAKEUP) flag so the device will wake from a sleep. From your alarm receiver you will need to take a wake lock (if you used RTC_WAKEUP) and start a service that will use the [NotificationManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html) to display a message to the user (very similar to the incoming SMS message).

As @WarrenFaith pointed out you will need to create a BOOT_COMPLETED receiver to re-establish the alarm after the phone is rebooted as they are not persistent.

Answer (score 2):

You need a [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) which can run when the app is not opened. You should also think about a [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) that listens to `BOOT_COMPLETED`

Comment: I'm thinking maybe an SMS message is what I want. Is there a class for that?

Comment: So you already know how he can run code when you app is not running? Well, than, as a user, I would prefer a simple notification because a SMS sounds always like a feature that cost me money...