# Auto Notification for Android

Tags: android, notifications

I'm new with Android programming. I'm just wondering whether its possible to set up auto notification. For example, every morning at 8am, the app will send a notification to user about something. Is this possible? Which area/class of Android programming should I look at? Thanks!

Comment: See my answer to here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6271323/how-to-notify-a-user-with-sms-or-notification-when-needed/6271905#6271905

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look at the [Alarm Manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html). You will need to use either of the 'set' methods, and give it a [PendingIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html) that will perform a broadcast or start an intent service that wakes up just to show the notification. For the broadcast, you will need to have a receiver in your app, that makes a Notification and shows it.